# Jquery on click (tap/vclick/touchstart) not working on real mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, onclick, drupal-8

to start off I've looked through the other stack overflow questions regarding this issue and none have helped me.  I'm using drupal 8.5.3 and jquery 3.2.1.

The issue I'm having is that "clicking" my mobile "show menu" button is not firing the jquery event to show or hide the mobile menu.  It works in chrome developer tools emulating a mobile device but on an actual device it's not working.

I've tried using "click", "touchstart", "vclick", and "touch" events and none of them have worked on a real device.  I've also tried using mobile jquery 1.4.5 and mobile jquery 1.5 alpha 1, neither of which have worked.  I'm out of ideas as to why it isn't working at this point, any help would be appreciated.

The html markup for the mobile menu:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item--expanded menu-item--active-trail">
        <span target="_self" class="mobile-menu-button" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>">Menu</span>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="/home" target="_self" class="mobile-menu-item" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/9">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item--active-trail">
                    <a href="/photos" target="_self" class="mobile-menu-item is-active" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/18">Photo</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="/media" target="_self" class="mobile-menu-item" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/23">Media</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="/press" target="_self" class="mobile-menu-item" data-drupal-link-system-path="press">Press</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="/resume" target="_self" class="mobile-menu-item" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/20">Résumé</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="/contact" target="_self" class="mobile-menu-item" data-drupal-link-system-path="contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The js click binding:

```
/**
 * @file
 * A JavaScript file for the theme.
 *
 * In order for this JavaScript to be loaded on pages, see the instructions in
 * the README.txt next to this file.
 */

// JavaScript should be made compatible with libraries other than jQuery by
// wrapping it with an "anonymous closure". See:
// - https://drupal.org/node/1446420
// - http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth
(function (Drupal, $) {
  'use strict';

  // To understand behaviors, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2269515
  Drupal.behaviors.basic = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      // Execute code once the DOM is ready. $(handler) not required
      // within Drupal.behaviors.
      $(window).on('load', function () {
        // Execute code once the window is fully loaded.
        $(".mobile-menu-button").parent().once().on("click", function() {
          $(".mobile-menu-button").parent().find(".menu").toggle();
        });
      });

      $(window).on('resize', function () {
        // Execute code when the window is resized.
      });

      $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        // Execute code when the window scrolls.
      });

    }
  };

})(Drupal, jQuery);
```

Comment: Try using JQuery's $(document).ready() instead of the window.onload, also why are you attaching the click handler to $('.mobile-menu-button').parent(), shouldn't you be attaching to the button itself?

Comment: I believe the $(window).on('load') is what needs to be used when working with drupal 8.  Document ready fires several times when loading a drupal page.

I'm attaching the event to the parent because the class is on a span within an unordered list and I want the click even to fire across the entire width of the li element instead of the span element contained within it.

Comment: @SocinD007 Ok, the event should still bubble up to the span.

Comment: @RyanWilson  Not quite sure I understand what you're saying. If I have the event on the span then it will only trigger if I click on the text "Menu".  If I have the event on the parent of the span (which is an li element in this case) then I can click next to the word "Menu" and the event will trigger which is desired.

Still, not sure why this works on desktop running chrome with responsive mode display but not on real mobile platforms.  I've tried with android and ios.

Comment: Do you get any errors on the mobile in dev mode?

Comment: Nope, no errors in dev mode.

Comment: Do you experience other things not working on the mobile device that work in your development environment?

Comment: Everything works except for the nav menu event firing.  Everything else on the site is using drupal's modules.  This nav menu is the only place I'm doing any custom javascript.

Comment: Have you tried changing from this: $(".mobile-menu-button").parent().find(".menu").toggle(); to this: $(".mobile-menu-button").parent().toggle(); It appears as if the span's parent is the item with class menu so the .find seems unnecessary.

Comment: The find is to get the nested menu that's under the menu li element.  The toggling isn't the problem so much as the event doesn't fire.  I've tried putting alert("test"); within the click event and it never fires on mobile devices (but does fire in the emulated chrome tools)

Comment: I've also tried setting the click event onto an img tag to see if I could even get it to fire with a less complicated scenario and it doesn't fire on mobile devices

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. Is the JQuery loading correctly?

Comment: I see jquery-mi.js version 3.2.1 in the network tab on my desktop and the event triggers on desktop.  I'll have to find a way to see if there's developer tools for mobile to see if my phone is getting the file too.

Comment: Yeah, at this point, I'm not sure what else it could be. Are you pulling in the JQuery file from an external link, or is it included in your project?

Comment: Drupal 8 includes jquery with it.  To include it in drupal 8 for your theme you modify the libraries.yaml file and add - core/drupal and -core/jquery which is how drupal 8 loads jquery for your theme which I have.  I'm thinking this is a jquery version issue or maybe there's some sort of bug with drupal 8 and jquery going on that I haven't found posted anywhere yet :/.  I'll try making a post on the drupal forums and see if anyone's run into this.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Good luck to you.

Comment: I made some headway on this while messing around with it.  It seems if I remove the once() method then it works on real mobile devices but NOT in google chrome responsive view.  Super weird bug that I'm gonna chalk up to drupal 8.

Comment: That is very strange. When I first read about that .once() I thought I read that it was necessary when using Drupal, but it sounds like it wasn't. Interesting problem and solution, and yeah, I agree that sounds like something that needs to be reported to the dev team at Drupal. Glad you got it working. Congrats!!

Answer (score 0):

In your own [module/theme].libraries.yml, you should set the ui,mouse as a dependency of your library:

```
dependencies:
  - core/jquery.ui.mouse
```